# How to do an array in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am making an investment calculator.

So I will be doing a math problem and I want to loop it through each array and there will be 12 of them.

So let's say I am going to invest $1000 with a rate return of 4.5%.

So I will need to do 1000 * 0.045 + 1000 = 1,045 that equals one month. Then I need to do 1,045 * 0.045 + 1,045 = 1,092 that would equal the second month and how would I have it go through a loop like that?

Would I use a for loop? or?

This is what I have so far maybe you'll get it better by reading it. But I still need to create a loop that would like the example I gave above.

```
public class SimpleInvestment {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double [] num = new double [11];
        printWelcome();
        double investTotal = getInvestAmount();
        double rateTotal = getRate();

    }

    public static void printWelcome()
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Investment Calulator");
    }

    public static double getInvestAmount()
    {
        double amountInvest;
        System.out.print("Hou much will you be investing?  ");
        amountInvest = input.nextDouble();
        while (amountInvest <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Amount must be greater than 0. Try again.");
            System.out.print("How much will you be investing?  ");
            amountInvest = input.nextDouble();
        }
        return amountInvest;
    }

    public static double getRate()
    {
        double rate;
        System.out.print("What will be the rate of return?");
        rate = input.nextDouble();
        while (rate < 0 )
        {
            System.out.println("Rate must be greater than 0. Try again.");
            System.out.print("What will be the rate of return?");
            rate = input.nextDouble();
        }
        return rate;
    }

    public static void calculateInterst( double num[], double investTotal, double rateTotal) 
    {
        double total; 
        rateTotal = rateTotal / 100;
        total = investTotal * rateTotal + investTotal;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not do 1000 * 1.045 for one month? etc..
Invest *for* x amount of months or *while* there is still an investment $amount present procure interest.

Comment: If you want your code reviewed post it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). If you ask about  how to repeatedly calculate  `1000 * 0.045 + 1000` , please remove all unrelated code like welcome and user-input related code. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while or for loop. In this example I used a for loop.

There is documentation in the code to walk you through the logic.

```
public static void calculateInterest(double num, double investTotal, double rateTotal) {
    double total; //keep the total outside loop
    rateTotal = rateTotal / 100; //your percent to decimal calculation
    total = investTotal * rateTotal + investTotal; //intial calculation

    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {//for loop starting at 1 because we alreay calculated the first

        total += (total * rateTotal);//just calculate the rate of change

    }

    System.out.println(total);//either output it or return it. Whatever you want to do from here.
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:
where months is the investment duration in months, 
investment is the amount that is being invested, 
rate is the interest rate. e.g. 0.045

```
    public static double calculateTotal(int months, double investment, double rate) {
        double total = investment;          
        for (int i=1; i <= months; i++) {
            total = total + (total * rate);
        }           
        return total;
    }
```